# Python: Overriding a Unknown class

Tags: python, decorator, overriding

Consider this example:

```
x = a.some_class_instance
x.foo()
```

I want to decorate `x.foo()`

something along the lines of

```
@x.foo()
def dec()    
    print 'decorator'    
    x.foo()
```

Is there anyway to do this?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is to do this:

```
x.foo = dec(x.foo)
```

Another way is to extend the instance's class

```
x = a.some_class_instance
class Extended(x.__class__):
    @dec
    def foo(...):
        ...
```

But I can't see any good reason to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The following code

```
@decorator
def decoratee():
    pass
```

is merely shorthand for

```
def decoratee():
    pass
decoratee = decorator(decoratee)
```

A decorator just takes a function as an argument and returns a new function.

Your example code *will* compile, and could actually run without errors depending on what x.foo does. But I highly doubt it would do what you want. I think what you want is something along the lines of:

```
def decorate(f):
    def decorated():
        print 'decorator'  
        f()
    return decorated
x.foo = decorate(x.foo)
```

Comment: I dont understand how decorated() would ever get called in that example? And how would I get access to x's namespace?

Comment: @Tony Medeiros: My bad; the `decorate` function should have returned a reference to `decorated` (fixed). You're right that in this example, `decorated` cannot access x's namespace. But it CAN access the old `x.foo` through the `f` argument passed to `decorate`, which is all your example needed. If you want access to all of x's namespace, then you must pass x as an argument to `decorate`.